# What value should I return in catch?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I just implemented a `Try` `catch` in my code, the error is because I have to return something in the `catch`,
I can't understand is "what should I return?"

> 'CompanyController.Create(DtoCompany)': not all code paths return a
> value [API]

```cs
[HttpPost("create/")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromBody] DtoCompany dto_company)
{
    try
    {
        var query = context.Companies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.rnc == dto_company.rnc);

        if (query != null)
        {
            Company comp = mapper.Map<Company>(query);
            context.Add(comp);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok("Registro de compania exitoso");
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest($"Ya existe una compañia con este RNC: `{dto_company.rnc}`");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error From Company-Create:", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If I write the `return` this, I getting an other error:

```cs
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return Console.WriteLine("Error From Company-Create:", ex.Message);
}
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult' [API]

Comment: its up to you what you want to return - you'll have to return something that produces the correct response!

Comment: You mean a HttpStatusCode for example 404?

Comment: Maybe, you could return an InternalServerError [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.internalservererror?view=aspnetcore-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.1] . Or return something after the catch block... or adding a finally block

Comment: If it's an unexpected server-side error then the standard would be a 500 Internal Server Error.  If you start seeing errors logged that could be handled differently, you can add specific `catch` blocks for those and return something more specific (bad request, not found, unauthorized, etc.).

Comment: this is correct? `            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Something wrong happened in the company-create:", ex);
            }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should return an error telling your client what went wrong.
A good way to to this is to return `Problem()`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

> 'CompanyController.Create(DtoCompany)': not all code paths return a
> value [API]
>
> I can't understand is "what should I return?"

If in the try block there's already a return statement, you  could put the other return at the end of the function, and this in order to avoid multiple returns if multiple exceptions need to be handled:

```
try
{
    //somecode
    return Ok();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error From Company-Create:", ex.Message);
}
return BadRequest();// add  this code
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't return anything from the `catch` part just a `MessageBox` or  `Console.WriteLine` which you implemented on the first block...
Simply `try catch` statement is to ask compiler to do something and if any error occurred in the code simply catch it and show it me using a `MessageBox` or   `Console.WriteLine`

Example:

```cs
try 
{
  sqlConnection conn = new sqlConnection(connection_string);
  conn.Open();
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
 if (ex.Message == "Certain specific error")
  MessageBox.Show("Do not do it");
else
  MessageBox.Show("Please do not do it");
```

Comment: This is wrong. It's an ASP.NET Core API action method, so neither of those would be seen by the caller.

Comment: Yes but you can show it some how in JSON

Comment: Yes, you would want to do that, but neither one of your suggestions allows you to do so. [musium's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72244070) does.